# How do I specify diffent binaries in CMake between debug and release when building for VS

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmake

I have two library binaries (debug an release) I need to point to the correct one when the user chooses between debug and release in VS. How do I in CMAKE instruct it to point to different directories. If I just use if statements only one will be set, but I need it to be done such that when I select between one or the other, the correct binary is selected and not that only debug or only release is set in the VS project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add them to your `target_link_libraries` command and prefix them with keywords `optimized` for Release and `debug` for Debug builds, e.g.

```
target_link_libraries(fancy_project PUBLIC optimized librelease.lib debug libdebug.lib)
```

See [documentation of target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html?highlight=target_link_libraries#overview) for an explanation of those keywords.